# jQuery .each() only prints last item from external Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to make a quiz using jQuery, and am pulling the questions and answers from an external Json file.

My problem is that my foreach loop only prints out the last element in the Json item.

This is my Jquery:

```
function postData(data) {
var html = "";

$.each(data, function(key, value) {

        html += "<ul><h3><span>" + key + "</span></h3>";

        $.each(value.answers, function(i, j){
            html += "<li>" + j.answer + "</li>";
        });

        html += "</ul>";

});

$('#content').append(html);

};
```

And an example of the data in my Json File is:

```
{
"Question Title":
    {
      "answers":
            [{
            "answer" : "answer one",
            "answer" : "answer two",
            "answer" : "answer three",
            "answer" : "answer four"
            }]
    },

"Question title two":
    {
      "answers":
            [{
            "answer" : "True",
            "answer" : "False"
            }]
    }
 }
```

However the only answers I get are:

```
Question title
- answer 4

Question title two
- False
```

Am I just trying loop through them oddly or am I not printing the objects properly?

Let me know if you need me to clarify on anything. Thank you.

Comment: html is invalid, `h3` can't be child of `ul`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JSON is flawed with duplicate property names in the same object.  Instead of this:

```
        [{
        "answer" : "answer one",
        "answer" : "answer two",
        "answer" : "answer three",
        "answer" : "answer four"
        }]
```

you want this where each answer property is in its own object:

```
        [
        {"answer" : "answer one"},
        {"answer" : "answer two"},
        {"answer" : "answer three"},
        {"answer" : "answer four"}
        ]
```

As you had it, you are duplicate property names in the same object which gives you the result of only the last property and is actually an error in strict mode (yet another reason to use strict mode) as the interpreter would have flagged this error for you.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/zesmjgq7/

---

You should probably also fix your HTML since there are only a few valid child objects of a `<ul>` (`<li>`, `<ul>` and `<ol>`) and an `<h3>` is not a legal child.  You could put the `<h3>` before the `<ul>` like this:

```
html += "<h3><span>" + key + "</span></h3><ul>";
```

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user3113376 - see the suggestion I added at the end to make your HTML legal too.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the key names in the answers Object

```
{
"Question Title":
    {
      "answers":
            [{
            "answer1" : "answer one",
            "answer2" : "answer two",
            "answer3" : "answer three",
            "answer4" : "answer four"
            }]
    },

"Question title two":
    {
      "answers":
            [{
            "answer1" : "True",
            "answer2" : "False"
            }]
    }
 };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/28w23mhh/